# How can I set the initial position of a scrollable image all the way to the right?

Tags: css, scroll

Ignore the php if it bothers you. I just added it for context of what I am doing. It is not important for the actual question.

I have an scrollable image that is larger than the screen and I want to initially see the right half of the image so the scroll bar is all the way to the right. With this code, the image starts all the way to the left as is normal. It can scroll to the right and works fine but I want it to start on the right. The $url image is a php generated graphical image showing 3 days of data and the most important data is today which is on the right of the image.

```
            echo "<div class = \"border container\">";
                echo "<img style=\"min-width:600;\" src=\"$url\">";
            echo "</div><br style=\"clear:both;\">";
```

My css

```
    .container {
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}


div.border{
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 900px;       
    background-color:white;
    margin-top:15px;
    margin-bottom:15px;
}
```

I tried this

```
echo "<img style=\"min-width:600;float:right;\" src=\"$url\">";
```

It does look like I want initially but it won't scroll

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If you are going to ask a question involving HTML, you should only show the HTML and not all the surrounding, irrelevant program. [mcve] and [ask]

Comment: I initially was going to post without the php but I thought it would be clearer if I indicated that the graph was data generated with a php so people would know why I wanted the right half to show. I guess I could have made up an image but the actual image name is a couple of hundred characters long.

Comment: Tried to give the image a `tabindex` of `1`? And play with `focus`?

Comment: `autofocus` does -- not -- work. But it should. Try outside JSFiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/yurm56d3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "direction:rtl;". I just removed the PHP code to show

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  direction: rtl;
}


div.border{
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 900px;       
  background-color:white;
  margin-top:15px;
  margin-bottom:15px;
}
```

```html
    <div class ="border container">;
        <img style="min-width:600" src="https://picsum.photos/1200/900">;
    </div><br style="clear:both">;
```

Comment: Thank you. I finally got it working using your suggestion. I very much appreciate it. I implemented it this way <div style="direction: rtl;" class = "border container"> so that I could selectively apply it to specific cases.

Comment: You are very welcome Allen and very happy that it helped. Happy coding 